# Horizontal Recycler View inside ViewPager not scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

### The Problem

I have a horizontal RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView which is inside a ViewPager. Now when I try to scroll the RecyclerView, sometimes it scrolls, but sometimes only the ViewPager scrolls.

### The Code

That's how my RecyclerView XML looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/sidescroll"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movie_more_movies2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_layout_keylines_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

That's how the Nested Scroll, in which the RecyclerView is, looks like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/detail_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
```

And this is the viewpager xml:

```
<com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.ViewPagerWithHorizontalRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

I am using this Custom ViewPager:

```
public class ViewPagerWithHorizontalRecyclerView extends ViewPager {

    public ViewPagerWithHorizontalRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ViewPagerWithHorizontalRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        if(v instanceof RecyclerView){
            Log.e("PAGER", "IS");
            return false;
        } else {
            Log.e("PAGER", "IS NOT " + v.toString());
        }

        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

### My Approach

What I tried so far, as you can see I wrote a custom ViewPager. I tried to tell the ViewPager that it can not scroll if the scroll comes from an RecyclerView. However this doesn't work.

### The Logs:

This is a log when the ViewPager scrolls instead of the RecyclerView

```
>     06-27 17:50:53.506 32362-32362/com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch E/PAGER: IS NOT
> com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch.ui.ViewPagerWithHorizontalRecyclerView{c506165
> VFED..... ........ 0,341-1080,1794 #7f090287 app:id/viewpager}
>     06-27 17:50:53.506 32362-32362/com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch E/PAGER: IS NOT android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView{d21952 VFED.....
> ........ 0,0-1080,1453 #7f0900b9 app:id/detail_holder}
>     06-27 17:50:53.506 32362-32362/com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch E/PAGER: IS NOT android.widget.RelativeLayout{6ddeec0 V.E...... ........
> 0,0-1080,2860 #7f090199 app:id/movie_overview_holder}
>     06-27 17:50:53.506 32362-32362/com.mt.moviesiwanttowatch E/PAGER: IS
```

Comment: Try setting  ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycleView,false);

Comment: I did, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

try to set onTouchListener for recycleView:

```
recycleView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        private float mLastX = 0, mLastY = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float deltaX = event.getX() - mLastX;
                    float deltaY = event.getY() - mLastY;
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 20 && Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    }
                    mLastX = event.getX();
                    mLastY = event.getY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            return onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use NonSwipeableViewPager following way. your pager will not work

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, that would work, but I don't want to remove the Scrolling Option from the pager

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView you should do this to your recycler (i use it for verical recycler).

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

I have exactly the same scenario on an app that I am working on. The ViewPager is scrolling not when I scroll the Horizontal Recycler, but when the Recycler is at the end of the list and has nothing to show. 
I hope I got your question right

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_30dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_90dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_90dp" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:typeface="gotham_medium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHoots"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:typeface="gotham_book" />

            <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSmiley"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                app:emojiSize="25sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMyFriends"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/red_rect_box"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/scale_15dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                android:text="@string/my_friends"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:typeface="bariol_bold" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:background="#eae6e6" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/light_grey" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:background="#eae6e6" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_10dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Here is my fragment XML filecode

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerMyStory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/scale_10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Fragment Java file

```
 recyclerMyStory = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerMyStory);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager1.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerMyStory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager1);

    recyclerMyStory.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    storyAdapter = new YourStoryAdapter(getActivity(), myStoryList, clickListener);
    recyclerMyStory.setAdapter(storyAdapter);

    ivCreate.setOnClickListener(this);
```